# Lenovo X1: How to get 100% scaling on the external monitor and 200% on the primary monitor?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, gnome, lenovo-laptop

I'm using Debian Bullseye with Xorg and Gnome on a new Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th w/ a 4k display.

Gnome scales the primary display to 200% which works but it applies the same scaling to the external monitor which is not 4k.

Does someone know how to get 100% scaling on the external monitor and 200% on the primary monitor?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028622/different-display-scale-settings-18-04

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your proposed edit. I got fed up tweaking xrandr commands for not-so-well working behavior. So I ended up with lowering my laptop monitor to a full-hd definition matching my external monitor. It gets a little blurry but for now it's more acceptable, than all the mouse flickering I get with xrandr and all the calculations I have to do to make it work (or so).

Comment: You are welcome.